# Why does cURLing a zip file require -L as a command line option?

Tags: shell, curl, terminal

If `curl -L` worked like plain `curl` did, or if I didn't need it to cURL a zip file without it corrupting, I wouldn't care. However, unzipping a zip file with plain `curl` always fails but `curl -L` works, and the time it takes to `curl -L` my zip file vs. the time it takes to download using Safari is concerning. I need to make my app that downloads and extracts a zip file, and I don't want this slow of speeds, especially since there are other downloads, that I can use plain `curl` for, that are big, so I want to conserve the users time.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @Ron I don't see what other code you need. I'm just using the `curl` command and wondering why my zip file gets corrupt along the way. `curl -Lo big-sur-micropatcher.zip https://github.com/barrykn/big-sur-micropatcher/archive/v0.4.3.zip` if you really want it. I'm not getting any errors, it's just slow. I did research to discover the `-L` option, which did not explain why it is slow though, in fact I could not find anything. You could at least be helpful instead of pointing out a whole bunch of made up flaws

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you give cURL the URL to a zip file, then:

- `curl` will download the zip file without corruption
- `curl -L` will download the zip file without corruption

However, web sites frequently don't link to zip files directly. Instead they link to a download page (e.g. "Your download is starting, click here if it doesn't").

If you give `curl` the URL to a redirecting download page, then:

- `curl` will download the web page, which obviously won't unzip.
- `curl -L` will follow the redirection and download the referenced zip file.

In either case there is no corruption. If you don't use `-L` and open the file in an editor, you'll see that it's plain HTML telling you to get the file somewhere else.

`curl -L` is slower than `curl` because downloading a web page plus a zip file is slower than downloading the web page alone. There's no getting around that if you want the file.

As for why Safari is faster than `curl -L`, that could have multiple explanations including, but not limited to, reusing a warm connection, using HTTP/3 with its reduced slow-start, or server-side throttling of scripted downloads. In any case it's more a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks! I found the direct download link and plain `curl` worked fine, but it is still slow though, especially for a 55 mb file.